# When I display this page the PHP part of the code is not working. It will not display the topics

Tags: php, html, css

Code will not display topics from database. I just get a blank pages.
Any solutions?
The pages loads but it will not display any thing. They want me to add more context but it breaks it so here you go.

```
<?php

//Database stuff.

include_once("connect.php");
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    trigger_error('Database connection failed: '  . $conn->connect_error,   E_USER_ERROR);
}else{
    mysqli_select_db($conn,"2159928_db");
}

$tid = '';

$cid = $_GET['cid'];
$tid = $_GET['tid'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM topics WHERE category_id='".$cid."' AND     id='".$tid."' LIMIT 1";


$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){
  echo "<table width ='75%'>";
  if (isset($_SESSION['uid'])) {

    //echo "<form action ='post_reply.php?cid=".$cid." &tid =".$tid. "'   method = 'post'>
    //<input type = 'submit' name = 'submit' value = 'Reply'/>";
    //echo "<tr><td colspan ='2'><center><input   type='submit'              value='Reply' onClick = 'window.open = 'post_reply.php?cid=".$cid." &tid =".$tid."' />";
    echo "<tr><td colspan ='2'><center><input type='submit'  value='Reply' onClick='window.open(\"post_reply.php?cid=$cid&tid=$tid\")'  />";

  } else {
    echo "<tr><td colspan = '2'><p><center> Please login to reply to  topics.</p></td></tr>";
  }  
   //Trying to display this. Doesn't even display border box.
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
       $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE category_id='".$cid."' AND  topic_id='".$tid. "'";
       $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);       
       while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){
           echo "<tr><td valign ='top' style = 'border: 5px solid  #ffffff;'><div style = 'min-height: 125px;'>".$row['topic_title']."<br/>
        by ".$row2['post_username']. " - " .$row2['post_date']. "<hr/>".$row2['post_content']."</div></td>";

       }
       //This part not relevant.
       $old_views = $row['topic_views'];
       $new_views = $old_views + 1;
       $sql3 = "UPDATE topics SET topic_views='".$new_views."' WHERE  category_id='".$cid."' AND id ='".$tid."' LIMIT 1";
    $result3 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql3);

  }

    echo "</table>";

} else {
    echo "<p>This topic does not exist.</p>";
}
?>
```

Comment: pls reformat your question.. now it's a big mess

Comment: small things first: you're missing a closing "</tr>" in loop for `$result1`

Comment: second: use [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). You have a security issue here.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't get frustrated. Asking the right question is difficult. For more information see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: question: do you have error-reporting on? `error_reporting(-1);` plus check for [mysqli-errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)

Comment: I am not too concerned about the security issues. I added the closing </tr> tag. Still trying to identify problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try echo-ing out your $sql to see if the query is correct.
If query is correct. Try var_dump to see if there are any results.